# Different intrinsics behaviour depending on GCC version

Tags: c++, gcc, undefined-behavior, intrinsics

I'm pretty new to intrinsics and i faced with different behavior of my code with GCC-7.4 and GCC-8.3

My code is pretty simple

b.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <xmmintrin.h>

void foo(const float num, const float denom)
{
    const __v4sf num4 = {
        num,
        num,
        num,
        num,
    };
    const __v4sf denom4 = {
        denom,
        denom,
        denom,
        denom,
    };
    float res_arr[] = {0, 0, 0, 0};

    __v4sf *res = (__v4sf*)res_arr;
    *res = num4 / denom4;
    std::cout << res_arr[0] << std::endl;
    std::cout << res_arr[1] << std::endl;
    std::cout << res_arr[2] << std::endl;
    std::cout << res_arr[3] << std::endl;
}
```

In b.cpp we just basically construct two `__v4sf` from float variables and performing division

b.h:

```
#ifndef B_H
#define B_H

void foo(const float num, const float denom);

#endif
```

a.cpp:

```
#include "b.h"

int main (void)
{
    const float denominator = 1.0f;
    const float numerator = 12.0f;
    foo(numerator, denominator);
    return 0;
}
```

Here we just call our function from b.cpp

GCC 7.4 works ok:

```
g++-7 -c b.cpp -o b.o && g++-7 a.cpp b.o -o a.out && ./a.out
12
12
12
12
```

But something wrong with GCC 8.3

```
g++-8 -c b.cpp -o b.o && g++-8 a.cpp b.o -o a.out && ./a.out
inf
inf
inf
inf
```

So my question is - why i receive different results with different versions of GCC? Is it undefined behavior?

Comment: You're using compiler-specific features.   By definition, it is undefined behaviour.  The meaning of "undefined" in the C++ standard is, essentially, "the C++ standard doesn't specify any constraints on what happens".      The standard certainly does not specify anything about any compiler-specific intrinsics you might use.   If you want to find out what's going on, read gcc documentation - probably for both versions that you are using.

Comment: @Peter thank you for comment! Can you tell me which particular section of documentation i should read? https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-8.3.0/gcc.pdf

Comment: @Peter It's not undefined, its [implementation defined](http://eel.is/c++draft/intro.defs#defns.impl.defined) (Because [`__v4sf` starts with `__`](http://eel.is/c++draft/lex#name-3.1)). Major difference, which basically means the standard side steps the issue and says "It is defined as: Does whatever the implementation (in this case gcc) wants it to do."

Comment: @Dark_Daiver Reading the definitions [here](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/gcc/config/i386/xmmintrin.h#L67-L75) seems like your running into aliasing issues and you want to use `__m128`

Comment: @Artyer thank you for comment! I'm pretty newbie, do you mean i should replace __v4sf with __m128? It doesn't help me =(

Comment: This looks like a bug in gcc (you can work around it by removing some `const`). Please report it to gcc's bugzilla so it can be fixed, thanks.

Comment: I always wonder why newbies (as claimed by Dark_Daiver) are often trying to explore compiler intrinsics first while (a lot of) experts prefer to write plain, portable, standard-conform code... Doing dark mysterious things seems to be tempting until you once recognize that the astethics of simple elegant code which achieves the same (without any dark mysterious ingredients) is much more desirable. (The dark side of the force...) ;-)

Comment: Does the problem still show up if you put everything in one file?

Comment: @L.F. as far as i remember, putting everything in one file makes everything works well.

Comment: @Scheff originally i faced with such problem in highly optimized code which was written by other guys. My post is just minimal example of a problem. Personally i prefer to avoid low level code/gpu code as much as possible. Sorry for my English

Comment: @MarcGlisse i created bug report https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=90810 (not sure that i formatted it correctly). Waiting for answer

Comment: Note that your code is broken at least for alignment reasons: `__v4sf` assumes 16-byte alignment, while res_arr only guarantees 4.

Comment: @MarcGlisse thank you for comment! 
I am not very well versed with memory alignment too. How can i make proper alignment for my output array? Is such definition ok? `static float res_arr[4] __attribute__ ((aligned (16)));` It still gives me same error, btw

Comment: Probably, though `static` has nothing to do with it, and `alignas` is more standard. Can't you just use a __v4sf instead of an array?

Comment: No problem https://gist.github.com/Daiver/ad4280b4fa4facef7cd4211396402379
Now i have `-nan`s

Comment: @Artyer: No, GNU C native vectors are allowed to alias their own element type without UB even if you omit `__attribute((__may_alias__))`.  Casting a `float*` to a `__v4sf*` never causes strict-aliasing UB.  Intel intrinsic types need `__may_alias__` because it's also legal to use them to read *anything*, like `uint64_t` data with a `__m128` float vector.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've found a bug in gcc8 and later, which happens with/without optimization enabled.  Thanks for [reporting it](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=90810).

With optimization enabled it's easy to see what the asm is doing because the `__v4sf` stuff optimizes away: it's just scalar division and printing the result 4 times.  (Plus 4 calls to flush cout because you used `std::endl` for some reason.)

gcc7 correctly optimizes it to `divss xmm0, xmm1` to do `num / denom`.  Then it converts to `double` because the output functions only take `double`, not `float`,  passes that to `iostream` functions.  (GCC7 saves the `double` bit-pattern in integer register `r14` instead of memory, with `-mtune=skylake`.  GCC8 and later just use memory which probably makes more sense.)

**gcc8 and later does `divss xmm0, .LC0[rip]` where the constant from memory is `0`** (the bit-pattern for `+0.0`).  So it's dividing the `num` by zero, ignoring `denom`.

Check it out on [the Godbolt compiler explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/cypD46).

Using `alignas(16) float res_arr[4];` to remove the potential under-alignment of the `__v4sf *res` doesn't help.  (You generally don't need `__attribute__((aligned(16)))` anymore; C++11 introduced standard syntax for alignment.)

---